# How to authenticate a pop application by using oauth 2 for outlook.office365.com in PHP

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, office365, pop3

I'm following [this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/legacy-protocols/how-to-authenticate-an-imap-pop-smtp-application-by-using-oauth#authenticate-connection-requests)

When I try to authenticate a POP server connection, I have an error :
"-ERR Authentication failure: unknown user name or bad password."
Even with a valid access_token

Here is my process so far.

I granted `POP.AccessAsUser.All` to my app on azure.

I'm connected with my user on Microsoft using the scope

```
offline_access https://outlook.office.com/POP.AccessAsUser.All
```

I retrieved a refresh_token,

With this refresh token, I requested a valid access_token with the scope

```
https://outlook.office.com/POP.AccessAsUser.All
```

With the access token and my email address, I generated the XOAUTH2

```
$XOAUTH2base64 = base64_encode("user=" .$this->username . "^Aauth=Bearer " . $this->token . "^A^A");
```

And the authentication fail

Here is a detail of the conversation (C : client, S: Server)

```
S: +OK The Microsoft Exchange POP3 service is ready. [...==]
C: AUTH XOAUTH2
S: +
C: {here i input my XOAUTH2base64} 
S: -ERR Authentication failure: unknown user name or bad password.
```

What im i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

My only mistake was generating `$XOAUTH2base64` wrong.

The correct way of doing it in PHP is :

```
        $XOAUTH2base64 = base64_encode("user=" .$this->username . "\1auth=Bearer " . $this->token . "\1\1");
```